# RedBean ORM ID Column

Tags: php, redbean

Is there a way to manually set the `ID` of a new bean using RedBean PHP? I'm storing cached data from an API which generates the `ID` of each row and would just like to use that `ID` for simplicity.

I've read other threads that say to simply create a new column (`row_id`) or something, but I'd like to just use the unique generated `ID` as the `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL doc

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   **assign 0 to the column** to generate sequence numbers. If the column is
>   declared **NOT NULL**, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to
>   generate sequence numbers. When you insert any other value into an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the
>   sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value
>   follows sequentially from the largest column value.

If that's true, in RedBean you can do something like

```
$post = R::dispense('post');
$post->id = 234;
R::store($post);
```

I haven't tested this since i keep auto-incremented column set to integer ***default to 0*** which automatically increments.

Answer (score 0):

I made a modified version of redbean, it allows you to use another field for primary key (with auto increment)
https://github.com/freelanceniek/redbeanx